# Rails 4 + Apache + Passenger: Image assets won't show for background-image

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to show an image using `background-image` but nothing I've tried will work. However, `image_tag()`s in the views work just fine.

I've tried:

`background-image: url("images/icons/heart.png")`

`background-image: url("icons/heart.png")`

`background-image: image-url("images/icons/heart.png")`

`background-image: image-url("icons/heart.png")`

`background-image: asset-url("images/icons/heart.png")`

`background-image: asset-url("/icons/heart.png")`

`background-image: asset-data-url("images/icons/heart.png")`

`background-image: url(image-path("icons/user_comment.png"))`

each time re running `rake assets:precompile`

Only asset-data-url has worked, but that because it stores the data of the image into the CSS, which is redundant. I can't for whatever reason get it to render the correct CSS in production. It always comes out to `background-image: url("/images/icons/heart.png")` or something similar where the hash at the end is not applied.

Most of these work in development.

Why would `image_tag` produce the correct url, while these won't?

Comment: how are you generating the css in production? are you using the right `RAILS_ENV`?

Comment: What production images are you using? If you're using the asset_sync gem, it messes up the images (we're working on a fix). How are your images being referenced in the CSS vs on the server?

Comment: @phoet `RAILS_ENV` is production. The CSS files are just stored in app/assets/stylesheets. @rich-peck I'm not using any gem in particular to reference the CSS. Locally, the CSS shows `background-image: url("assets/icons/heart.png")`.

Comment: @h7u9i it looks like the assets are compiled with development environment.

Comment: @phoet Any idea on how to change that? I definitely specifying `production` when I start Apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out the problem, I was compiling the assets incorrectly.

I needed to run

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

instead just of just `rake assets:precompile`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a simple CSS file or an SASS/SCSS file?  That may be too basic a suggestion, but to me it sounds like you're using straight CSS, for which I don't think the image-url, etc. directives will be evaluated.

Comment: Yes, it's `application.css.scss`.